# Print the output of php/js file to textarea

Tags: php, textarea, save, elgg

I use the CMS ELGG (http://www.elgg.org) that records different entities, and I created a page that list all the posters and to html with some javascript to allow the inner the user to print pre-formatted list, but also with choices javascript to print or not these entities

So I would like to save this page, possibly in a textarea field, so the user can retrieve this page.
If I run all my functions inside a textarea tag, php variables work, but not allowing the javascript setting form, there is also a conflict with the checkbox that I inserted in front of these entities, allowing the choice to print or not, that do not work inside the textarea ...

So I have no idea how to save this page and allow the user to save multiple pages of this type so that it can use multiple models.

I have read several issues of this type for php functions ob ob flush start ... but I have not found anything that works for me

If someone have some idea for me ...

Thanks ;)

**Example from php file**

```
<div id="engagements" class="blockcv">
    <div class="comptitrecv"><input type="checkbox" value="" id="printengagements" class="checkprint" checked="checked"/> Engagement citoyen</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
function sortDescending(a, b) {
     var date1  = $(a).find("span").text();
       date1 = date1.split('/');
     date1 = new Date(date1[1], date1[0] -1, 1);
     var date2  = $(b).find("span").text();
       date2= date2.split('/');
     date2 = new Date(date2[1], date2[0] -1, 1);

     return date1 < date2 ? 1 : -1;
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.shakeengagements .elementengagements').sort(sortDescending).appendTo('.shakeengagements');
    }); 
</script>
<div class="shakeengagements">
     <?php
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$count_experiences = count_user_objects($user->guid, "experience");
$experiences = get_user_objects($user->guid, "experience", 99);
foreach ($experiences as $ent) { 
 ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">  
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hide<?php echo $ent->guid; ?>').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('div#hidediv<?php echo $ent->guid; ?>').removeClass("noprint");
    } else {
        $('div#hidediv<?php echo $ent->guid; ?>').addClass("noprint");
    }
});
});
  </script>
<div class="elementengagements" id="hidediv<?php echo $ent->guid; ?>">
<div class="cvelleft">
<p><span><input type="checkbox" value="" id="hide<?php echo $ent->guid; ?>" class="checkprint" checked="checked"/>
<?php 
    $classementdates = $ent->ongoing;
    $enddate = $ent->enddate;
    if ($classementdates == 'ongoing') {
     echo '<span class="date">'; 
     echo $ent->startdate; 
     echo '<font style="display:none">9</font></span> - ';
     echo elgg_echo('resume:acejour');
     } else {
            if(empty($enddate)) {
                     echo '<span class="date">'; 
     echo $ent->startdate; 
     echo '<font style="display:none">9</font></span>';

            } else {
         echo $ent->startdate;
         echo ' - <span>';
         echo  $ent->enddate;
         echo '</span>';
     } 

     }
     ?> </span>:</p>
</div>
<div class="cvelright"> 
<p><?php echo $ent->heading; ?> - <?php echo $ent->structure; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $ent->remarques; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php   } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear what you want to do exactly, but to me it sounds like you want the above to be rendered, then appear in a `textarea`?

If you want to do that, then I don't see why ob_start won't work if it is on the same page:

```
ob_start();
//your code that you want to appear in the textarea
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo "<textarea>".$output."</textarea>";
```

If it is a separate page, then you could always do:

```
$output = file_get_contents("/path/to/php_file.php");
echo "<textarea>".$output."</textarea>";
```

If you want to be able to read the `textarea` as HTML, then might I also suggest `htmlentities($output)` within the `textarea` tags, ie.:

```
echo "<textarea>".htmlentities($output)."</textarea>";
```

But note, that if you are submitting the textarea to a form to save, you will see a lot of HTML entities, for example, a copyright symbol - © - will convert to & copy; (note: I have to put a space between the & and copy; otherwise you cannot see what I mean) - but visibly it will be the same.

**Update**

You can use jQuery for this, and it should work - everything within the `div with id:`engagements`will get copied into the`textarea`. If you don't want the javascript (or anything else) to appear in the`textarea`, then don't put it wihin the`div`. I'd keep the below out of that`div` for a start...

```
<input type="checkbox" id="form_submit" name="form_submit" value="yes">
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
<script>
    $(document).read(function(){
        $("#form_submit").click(function(){
            if($(this).checked){
                $("#output").val($("#engagements").text());
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The above is untested, but should work in theory!

Comment: Hello MrJ,

thanks for your answer, more clearly, I would like the page I made is displayed in html, with the checkbox that are checkable or not, and once completed, at a click of a button save the whole page to be saved html.
If I write the function as you have shown me, I have a textarea but the checkbox does not work ...